# WebAPI + OData Service on IIS 5

Tags: wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api, odata

We are facing a problem with our clients who are running on IIS 5.  Our Data Server uses a combination of WebAPI and OData to return information and I'm having trouble getting both to work at the same time.

I believe the problem is coming down to the extension Mappings in IIS.  We had the OData Service working fine, but the WebAPI wasn't, so we added a .* extension mapping and that fixed the WebAPI stuff, but then the OData Service failed.

Both fail with an "Error 404 - Object not found".

The ".svc" mapping and ".*" mapping are both using the same version of aspnet_isapi.dll.

Does anyone know how to have both of these technologies running on IIS 5?

Comment: Let me know if this helps http://goo.gl/xVZd2

Comment: Thanks, but that is the solution to getting the WebAPI running which we have already implemented as mentioned above.  The issue is it breaks the OData Service.